# Graficar Arbol binario usando libreria Matplotlib

Tags: python

Saludos compañeros de stackoverflow Tengo el siguiente problema:
Me toco realizar un programa en donde genera ciertos números random y en ese mismo orden generado, se genera la grafica del árbol binario, pero tuve problemas al mostrar el árbol ya que se me llegan a cruzar los nodos de modo a imprimirse uno sobre otro
El código siguiente es el que estoy usando para graficar y que es donde supongo que tengo el error.

```
def visual(self):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    an = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    fig, axs = plt.subplots()

    fig.set_size_inches(8, 6)
    axs.clear()
    axs.set_axis_off()

    def text(px, py, _text):
        axs.text(px, py, _text, backgroundcolor="white", ha='center', va='top', color='black')
    correction = 0

    for i in self.__names__:
        print(i[1]) #imprime el numero de nodo
        print(i[2]) #posicion en x
        print(i[3]) #posicion en y
        print(i[4]) #altura de arbol
        if i[2] == 0 and i[3] == 0:
            axs.plot(0 + .4 * np.cos(an), 0 + .4 * np.sin(an))
        #-- MONEDA RAIZ Y NUMERO RANDOM ------------------------------------
            text(0, 0, "%s %s" % (i[0], i[1]))
            plt.pause(.15)
            continue
        #-- RAMA DERECHA ---------------------------------------------------
        if i[5] == "r":
            correction = self.__add_count__ - 1
        #-- RAMA IZQUIERDA -------------------------------------------------
        elif i[5] == "l":
            correction = - self.__add_count__ + 1

        x2 = i[2] + correction
        y2 = i[3]
        #-- PRIMERA RAMA ---------------------------------------------------
        if y2 == -1:
            x1 = i[4]
        else:
            x1 = i[4] + correction
        y1 = y2 + 1
        #-- DIBUJA CIRCULOS ------------------------------------------------
        axs.plot(x2 + .4 * np.cos(an), y2 + .4 * np.sin(an))
        #-- MONEDA Y VALOR RANDOM ------------------------------------------
        text(x2, y2, "%s %s" % (i[0], i[1]))
        plt.pause(.15)
        #-- DIBUJA LINEA DE UNION ------------------------------------------
        axs.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2])
        plt.pause(.15)
```

estos son los numeros generados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es la forma en que se imprimio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He planteado la opción de poder expandir la distancia del nodo padre de otros para tener un mayor campo para desarrollar los hijos pero aun no logro codificar la idea.
Cualquier aporte es agradecido.
pd. es primera vez usando esta librería para poder graficar grafos

Answer (score -1):

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Node:
def **init**(self, val):
self.val = val
self.left = None
self.right = None

def build_tree(nums):
root = Node(nums[0])
for num in nums[1:]:
insert_node(root, num)
return root

def insert_node(root, val):
if root is None:
return Node(val)
if val < root.val:
root.left = insert_node(root.left, val)
else:
root.right = insert_node(root.right, val)
return root

def plot_tree(root, x, y, ax):
if root is None:
return
ax.scatter(x, y, s=200, facecolors='none', edgecolors='black')
if root.left:
ax.plot([x, x-1], [y-1, y+1], c='black')
plot_tree(root.left, x-1, y+1, ax)
if root.right:
ax.plot([x, x+1], [y-1, y+1], c='black')
plot_tree(root.right, x+1, y+1, ax)

def visual(nums):
root = build_tree(nums)
fig, axs = plt.subplots()

```
fig.set_size_inches(8, 6)
axs.clear()
axs.set_axis_off()

def text(px, py, _text):
    axs.text(px, py, _text, backgroundcolor="white", ha='center', va='top', color='black')

def plot_node(node, x, y):
    axs.plot(x + .4 * np.cos(an), y + .4 * np.sin(an))
    text(x, y, str(node.val))

an = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
nodes = [[root, 0, 0]]
while nodes:
    node, x, y = nodes.pop()
    plot_node(node, x, y)
    if node.left:
        axs.plot([x, x-1], [y-1, y+1])
        nodes.append([node.left, x-1, y+1])
    if node.right:
        axs.plot([x, x+1], [y-1, y+1])
        nodes.append([node.right, x+1, y+1])

plt.show()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
nums = [6, 90, 88, 4, 36, 65, 68, 54, 5, 82, 28, 50, 51, 32, 47, 60, 64, 53, 89, 7, 13, 85, 56, 0, 14]
visual(nums)

Comment: Esto es una respuesta???

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

esto es lo que yo hice

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Node:
def **init**(self, val):
self.val = val
self.left = None
self.right = None

def build_tree(nums):
root = Node(nums[0])
for num in nums[1:]:
insert_node(root, num)
return root

def insert_node(root, val):
if root is None:
return Node(val)
if val < root.val:
root.left = insert_node(root.left, val)
else:
root.right = insert_node(root.right, val)
return root

def plot_tree(root, x, y, ax):
if root is None:
return
ax.scatter(x, y, s=200, facecolors='none', edgecolors='black')
if root.left:
ax.plot([x, x-1], [y-1, y+1], c='black')
plot_tree(root.left, x-1, y+1, ax)
if root.right:
ax.plot([x, x+1], [y-1, y+1], c='black')
plot_tree(root.right, x+1, y+1, ax)

def visual(nums):
root = build_tree(nums)
fig, axs = plt.subplots()

```
fig.set_size_inches(8, 6)
axs.clear()
axs.set_axis_off()

def text(px, py, _text):
    axs.text(px, py, _text, backgroundcolor="white", ha='center', va='top', color='black')

def plot_node(node, x, y):
    axs.plot(x + .4 * np.cos(an), y + .4 * np.sin(an))
    text(x, y, str(node.val))

an = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
nodes = [[root, 0, 0]]
while nodes:
    node, x, y = nodes.pop()
    plot_node(node, x, y)
    if node.left:
        axs.plot([x, x-1], [y-1, y+1])
        nodes.append([node.left, x-1, y+1])
    if node.right:
        axs.plot([x, x+1], [y-1, y+1])
        nodes.append([node.right, x+1, y+1])

plt.show()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
nums = [6, 90, 88, 4, 36, 65, 68, 54, 5, 82, 28, 50, 51, 32, 47, 60, 64, 53, 89, 7, 13, 85, 56, 0, 14]
visual(nums)

Comment: Y esto es otra respuesta distinta???

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).